# Freezing the tool tip after clicking on it

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am trying use org.eclipse.jface.window.DefaultToolTip to display some UI components like checkbox,radio buttons placed on composite. When user clicks on a text, the tooltip with pops up to and displays the UI components.

Issue: I want to freeze tool tip once user clicks inside this tooltip. Using `toolTip.setHideOnMouseDown(false);` I am able to check/un-check the check boxes/radio buttons as long as I am inside the tool tip area. Once mouse pointer exits the tool tip area, the tooltip disappears. How can this be avoided. I am looking for similar behaviour which is available for eclipse tooltips( javadoc, method definition). In Eclipse tooltip, if we click/press f2, tooltip will remain active until we click outside of the tooltip area.

**Edit**: I also tried to use Eclipse Plugin Spy on tooltip, but no success.

Any thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Eclipse does when F2 is pressed is to create a new Shell with exactly the same size and contents as the tooltip and closes the original tooltip.

I use code like the following in an extended tooltip class:

```
  /**
   * Switch from tool tip to a normal window.
   */
  private void showWindow()
  {
    if (_control.isDisposed())
      return;

    final Shell shell = new Shell(_control.getShell(), SWT.CLOSE | SWT.ON_TOP | SWT.RESIZE);

    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    createBody(shell);

    final Point currLoc = _parent.getShell().getLocation();

    final Rectangle client = _parent.getClientArea();

    final Rectangle bounds = shell.computeTrim(currLoc.x, currLoc.y, client.width, client.height);

    shell.setBounds(bounds);

    shell.open();

    // Hide the tool tip window

    hide();
  }
```

`_control` is the control passed to the constructor.